# CSS Not Loading on 404 Page

Tags: html, css, http-status-code-404, loading

When I go to the 404 page on my website it doesn't load any of the CSS.
Note that the style directory is in the main directory where the 404.html is.

This is my HTML: https://hastebin.com/geharusoyo.scala

This is what the 404 page looks like: https://fluxdesigns.org/404

Thanks!
TrifleTower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

Instead of:

```
<link rel="css/sheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

Comment: Got the css working but for some reason it's messed up. fluxdesigns.org/404

Answer (score 1):

Your stylesheets are `<link rel="css/sheet"...` and they need to be `<link rel="stylesheet"...`

Comment: Got the css working but for some reason it's messed up.
https://fluxdesigns.org/404/

Comment: @TrifleTower look in your browser console.

Comment: All the stuff not loading in the console is not needed on that page.

Comment: @TrifleTower then you need to be more specific. "it's messed up" doesn't mean anything to me - I don't know how it's supposed to look and this isn't in your post, so I'm just taking a guess.

Comment: Well, it's meant to not have the random grey boxes everywhere and the ones on the main part are meant to be buttons with text.

Comment: @TrifleTower look at your page source. Validate the page. You can troubleshoot this. Your post needs one clear problem, well described, and ideally with the code on SO and not in a 3rd party site. Seems that grey box is coming from a broken tag that is repeated all over the page. `<a class="order-now-button" href="/contact"Order Now</a>`